# How to keep a predefined db file and open it with SQLiteDatabase class in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am currently using `SQLiteDatabase myDatabase=this.openOrCreateDatabase("conference",MODE_PRIVATE,null);` for opening the database on the app side and `myDatabase.execQuery()` for executing queries. Now when I was testing with different devices I found that when I installed the apk file on other phones, the database I prepared with execQuery() did not carry to other phones.

I am looking to solving this problem. I assume I must keep a already-prepared `.db` file somewhere in the raw folder and then open the database from there.

How can I do that?

Comment: You just answered your own question. You'll need to package the .db file inside of the working directory of the app.

Comment: Check library https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Answer (score -1):

You should try to implement Singleton class for application rather than database,because database is created in android you cannot add them as raw db

example of singleton class

```
 public class CrimeLab {
    private static CrimeLab sCrimeLab;

    private List<Crime> mCrimes;
    public static CrimeLab get(Context context) {
        ...
    }
    private CrimeLab(Context context) {
        mCrimes = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public List<Crime> getCrimes() {
        return mCrimes;
    }
    public Crime getCrime(UUID id) {
        for (Crime crime : mCrimes) {
            if (crime.getId().equals(id)) {
                return crime;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```